# Show loading screen globally in React.js while calling it from different pages

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I was trying to implement a global loading screen when fetching data from an API, I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69110667) and tried to implemented something similar.

**loading.provider.js**

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const LoadingContext = createContext({
  loading: false,
  setLoading: null
});

export function LoadingProvider({ children }) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const value = { loading, setLoading };
  return (
    <LoadingContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</LoadingContext.Provider>
  );
};

export function useLoading() {
  const context = useContext(LoadingContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useLoading must be used within LoadingProvider');
  }

  return context;
};
```

**app.js**

The LoadingScreen has been added to this screen:

```
import Layout from '@/components/Layout/Layout';
import { LoadingProvider, useLoading } from '@/Providers/loading.provider';
import LoadingScreen from "./LoadingScreen";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const { loading } = useLoading();

  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <LoadingProvider>
        <AppStateProvider>
          { loading && <LoadingScreen loading={true} bgColor='#fff' spinnerColor={'#00A1FF'} textColor='#676767'></LoadingScreen> }
          <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
        </AppStateProvider>
      </LoadingProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

I have a Layout component which holds a `SideMenu`, top `AppBar` and the `main` components:

**Layout.js**

```
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <AppBar />
        <SideMenu />
        <Box component="main" sx={mainContentWrapper}>
          <div className={styles.container}>
            <main className={styles.main}>
              {children}
            </main>
          </div>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Now I was trying to show it from a page (**[identifier].js**):

```
import { useLoading } from "@/Providers/loading.provider";

export default function MainPage({ response }) {
  const { loading, setLoading } = useLoading();
  const btnClickedAll = async (data) => {
    setLoading(true);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Button sx={{ ml: 2 }} key={'btnAll'} onClick={btnClickedAll} variant="contained">All</Button>,
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

`loading` is being called after setting it with `setLoading(true)` but the state is not changing inside **app.js**. Can someone help me and point me to the right direction?

---

Edited: Made some changes in code according to @DustInComp suggestion.

Comment: You named the value `loading`, not `isLoading`. Fix it in Layout.js

Comment: Amazing, thank you, I have another question, I moved the implementation from `Layout.js` into `app.js` and it stoped working, you have an idea what may cause it?

Comment: You are trying to read the `loading` state before it is set. You need to call `useLoading` anywhere within the `<LoadingProvider>` component. This is why you have the `if(!context)` inside the `useLoading` function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your **LoadingProvider** is inside of your **app.js**, and only children inside off the **LoadingProvider** would have access to the loading state.

**Option 1**

What you could do is to move wrap the entire **app.js** in **LoadingProvider** in the parent, maybe **index.js**.

In **index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import './index.css';
import './bootstrap.min.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <LoadingProvider>
        <App />
    </LoadingProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**OR**

**Option 2**

You could create a child component of everything inside of **app.js**.

In **Child.js** (Name it as you please)

```js
const Child = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    const { loading } = useLoading();
     <AppStateProvider>
          { loading && <LoadingScreen loading={true} bgColor='#fff' spinnerColor={'#00A1FF'} textColor='#676767'></LoadingScreen> }
          <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
     </AppStateProvider>
};

export default Child;
```

And in **app.js**

```js
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <LoadingProvider>
        <Child Component={Component} pageProps={pageProps}/>
      </LoadingProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

**OR**

**Option 3**

You could create a loader component of the loader and import it into `app.js`.

In **Loader.js** (Name it as you please)

```js
const Loader = () => {
    const { loading } = useLoading();
    return loading && <LoadingScreen loading={true} bgColor='#fff' spinnerColor={'#00A1FF'} textColor='#676767'></LoadingScreen>;        
};

export default Loader;
```

And in `app.js`

```js
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <LoadingProvider>
        <AppStateProvider>
          <Loader />
          <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
        </AppStateProvider>
      </LoadingProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in the second option that you've provided, where does the `...PageProps` is coming from?

Comment: Btw, I cannot find the `ReactDOM.render` in my project. Does it has anything to do with that I am using `Next.js`?

Comment: Pageprops needs to be passed from `app.js` to the `Child`.

Comment: Oh, just saw that you've made some changes to the answer. Trying it now. Thanks!

Comment: `Next.js` probably does `ReactDOM.render` under the hood, you would probably not be able to see it. The idea is to delegate the `LoadingProvider` to the parent of `app.js` so that you can access the state inside. However if `app.js` is a seperate page since you are using Next.js, you could use the second approach of creating a child component.

Comment: Ok, i've made some changes according to your changes and implemented the second solution that you've provided, but I can only see white screen.

Comment: I made a small error in the second option where I didn't add the return keyword. 
I also added an alternate solution, both should work, please give it a try!

Comment: The problem is what I had before, it adds the `LoadingScreen` before the `__next` `div` and not on top of it.

Comment: Okay, that is because you are rendering the other divs later on. You could use option 2 and use the ternary operator to only render loading screen if it is loading. 
Or if you want to use option 3, you could make the loading screen come on top of the main screen using `position: absolute;` in CSS. I would recommend using the former.

Comment: I did it and it shows, but it shows in the middle of the main content and not on the top of `SideBar` and `AppBar`. (I used the 3rd solution option that you provided)

Comment: I guess you would need to play around with css for it. I believe the context logic is working now!