# React.js/Next.js Loader is showing in the wrong place on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-context

I want to show a Loader on top of everything while fetching data from my API. I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75434440/1138498) and implemented the answer, and it is working, but it shows it not on top level, but inside the page itself. When looking at the html tree I can see that it is on the top level.

This is what happens when `btnAll` is clicked:

[image]

After scrolling down:

[image]

This is the HTML tree:

[image]

Why does it put it inside the page?

**loading.provider.js**

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const LoadingContext = createContext({
  loading: false,
  setLoading: null
});

export function LoadingProvider({ children }) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const value = { loading, setLoading };
  console.log(`LoadingProvider: ${loading}`);
  return (
    <LoadingContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</LoadingContext.Provider>
  );
};

export function useLoading() {
  const context = useContext(LoadingContext);
  console.log(`Using LoadingContextProvider`);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useLoading must be used within LoadingProvider');
  }

  return context;
};
```

**app.js**

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppStateProvider>
        <LoadingProvider>
          <Loader />
          <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
        </LoadingProvider>
      </AppStateProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Loader.js**

```
import { useLoading } from "@/Providers/loading.provider";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import LoadingScreen from "./LoadingScreen";

const Loader = () => {
  const { loading } = useLoading();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`[app.js/#useEffect]: useLoading() value changed to: ${loading}`);
  }, [loading]);

  return loading && <LoadingScreen loading={true} bgColor='#fff' spinnerColor={'#00A1FF'} textColor='#676767'></LoadingScreen>;        
};

export default Loader;
```

**LoadingScreen.js**

```
import styles from './LoadingScreen.module.css';

export default function LoadingScreen() {

  return (
    <div className={styles.loading}>
      <div className={styles.dot}></div>
      <div className={styles.dot}></div>
      <div className={styles.dot}></div>
      <div className={styles.dot}></div>
      <div className={styles.dot}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the css part of `style.loading` inside `LoadingScreen.module.css`:

```
.loading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I am calling it inside `[identifier].js` page like that:

```
import { useLoading } from "@/Providers/loading.provider";

export default function MainPage({ response }) {
  const { loading, setLoading } = useLoading();
  const btnClickedAll = async (data) => {
    setLoading(true);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Button sx={{ ml: 2 }} key={'btnAll'} onClick={btnClickedAll} variant="contained">All</Button>,
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

Try set the style `.loading` `position: fixed;`

---

Old:

Try moving down the `<Loader />` in **app.js**

```
...
        <LoadingProvider>
          <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
          <Loader />
        </LoadingProvider>
...
```

Or it's better to put Loader in **loading.provider.js** and remove `<Loader />` from **app.js**

```
...
    <LoadingContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
      <Loader />
    </LoadingContext.Provider>
...
```

Comment: Still the same problem..

Comment: Ahhh, just checked your question again, and realized you met the problem when you scroll down the page. updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, but now it's above the whole page except the `Top Navigation Bar` and `Sidebar`. How do I make it on top of everything?

Comment: @ytpm to make an element on top of everything, we usually put the element as the last child of the body tag.